# Datapreprocessing TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Tags: python, string, list, typeerror, data-preprocessing

I'm writing a function for text preprocessing on a dataset:

```
def text_transform(text):
    text = text.lower()
    text = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    
    x = []
    for i in text:
        if i.isalnum():
            x.append(x)
            
    text = x[:] 
    x.clear() 
    
    for j in text:
        if j not in stopwords.words('english') and j not in string.punctuation:
            x.append(j)
    return x
```

And I am getting the error on the stopwords part:

```
 TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
 last) <ipython-input-52-7f819487e6f8> in <module>
 ----> 1 text_transform('Hello How are you ?')
 
 <ipython-input-51-4ace2423bd95> in text_transform(text)
      12 
      13     for j in text:
 ---> 14         if j not in stop and j not in string.punctuation:
      15             x.append(j)
      16     return x
 
 TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list
```

Comment: `x.append(x)` Nope

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Don't re-append the same list.

```
x.append(x)
```

Only the string

```
x.append(i)
```

Better yet use list comprehension

```
x = [i for i in text if i.isalnum()]
```